# Task Scheduler is failed with Error Value: 2147942405 without using SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure and want to execute it to run every day. So I'm using windows task scheduler since SQL Server Express does not have SQL Server Agent.

I created .bat file and Test.Sql

In .bat file command is as below;

```
@Echo On

sqlcmd -Slocalhost -UUsername -PPassword -dDBName -i"Test.sql" -u 

EXIT
```

In Test.sql file command is as below;

```
EXEC    @return_value = [DBName].[dbo].[SP_Test]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

But I got this error message in task scheduler:

> Task Scheduler failed to start instance "{81262453-1610-4f3b-90aa-4fbd48c5cd58}" of "\Test"  task for user "AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE" . Additional Data: Error Value: 2147942405.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Have you tried searching for the error? Have you tried running a bat file on its own (from cmd)?

Comment: include your sp_test script